# Explain this winter bash task "Epiphany" (2016/17)

Tags: support, winter-bash

At this time everyone is excited about Winter Bash.
Can someone explain what task is this? (It looks some other language which I am not familiar with)

[image]

Answer (score 18, accepted):

The task for the Epiphany hat is to vote or post on January 6th (that is [Epiphany](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Epiphany_(holiday)), which is part of the Christmas holidays). 
This is visible before clicking on the hat. The text you ask about is Italian, yet does not explain the task. It seems to be a reference to a song that I am given to understand somewhat fits the context. It roughly means "The Befana comes at night with completely broken shoes." and in Italian folklore [Befana](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Befana) is an old woman that brings gifts the night before Epihany.

Comment: I didn't know you liked hats. :)

Comment: Well, seem like a case of, if you can't beat them, join them. :-) But I already wore hats the last two seasons I think. In a funny coincidence just there I  (am forced to) hear "Last Christmas" the first time this season.

Comment: [This should be the song](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Tyvm7DTu9Fk). "rotte" means "broken", not "rotten" :).

Comment: Better song: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=RZAGeRJCQ1s